# Using Bootstrap Components to Submit Data to an Asp.Net Core Web API Backend

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, forms, angular, frontend, twitter-bootstrap-4

I have the following submit button and corresponding text from a bootstrap template:

```
  <div class="col-sm-6">
     <div class="form-group">
         <input class="form-control input-lg" type="text" id="inputLarge">
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class = "navbar-brand">
     <div class="col-sm-2">
         <div class="form-group">
             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
         </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

In this tutorial, https://jonhilton.net/2017/02/01/send-form-input-via-an-angular-2-component-to-asp-net-core-web-api/, it uses the following button:

```
<input type="text" id="city" [(ngModel)]="chosenCity" />
<input type="button" value="Get Weather" (click)="getWeather(chosenCity)" />
```

I am confused as to how I can do this using my bootstrap buttons (and more generally bootstrap bits) as ultimately this is what I want to be able to do. Does anyone know how to use bootstrap components to submit data to an asp.net core web api?

Comment: uh, I don't understand the problem here and what does this have to do with dotnet?

Comment: Just check out forms in angular: https://angular.io/guide/forms and apply the bootstrap classes. Other than that, this is a pure Angular form.  Go for reactive or template-driven: https://angular.io/guide/forms :)

Comment: @AJT_82 it doesnt have anything to do with asp.net in particular just really any backend in general (eg could be django)

Comment: Well yeah, first maybe build the form, then consider how to actually post it to the backend ;) When that time comes, then look at https://angular.io/guide/http :)

Comment: @AJT_82 Ill have a look at the above in a sec, just when i looked the tutorials never use bootstrap

Comment: @AJT_82 the problem with a lot of these web dev tutorial is that they use technoloiges totally in isolation

Comment: It doesn't matter if they do not use bootstrap in this case, you use Angular components, directives etc, then just **style** your form with bootstrap. And btw, the live examples docs use, are using bootstrap styling actually.